# Button Click URL + String

Tags: c#, string, url, button, uri

I am trying to have a click event navigate the webBrowser to a pre-set location + string but I can't seem to get it to work.

My biggest issue is maybe getting the string from one event to the click event?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Ink
{
    public partial class inkForm : Form
    {

        public inkForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string searchlink;

        private void searchbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.AcceptButton = searchbutton;

            int itemrow = -1;
            String searchValue = searchtextBox.Text.ToUpper();

            if (searchValue != null && searchValue != "")
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in inkGridView.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
                    {
                        itemrow = row.Index;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains(searchValue) && itemrow == -1)
                    {
                        itemrow = row.Index;
                    }
                }
                if (itemrow == -1)
                {
                    searchtextBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
                else
                {
                    searchtextBox.BackColor = Color.White;
                    inkGridView.Rows[itemrow].Selected = true;
                    inkGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = itemrow;
                }
            }
        }

        private void inkForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.hPTableAdapter.Fill(this.inkDataSet.HP);

        }

        private void updatebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to update the stock level?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                this.hPTableAdapter.Update(inkDataSet.HP);
                inkGridView.Refresh();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Updated.", "Success!");
            }

        }
        private void inkGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            inkGridView.Columns["tonerInkDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].ReadOnly = true;
        }

        private void inkGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (inkGridView.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            {
                int selectedrowindex = inkGridView.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

                DataGridViewRow selectedRow = inkGridView.Rows[selectedrowindex];

                string searchlink = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["tonerInkDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
            }
        }

        private void orderbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string link;
            string searchlink = "blahblah";
            link = "http://store.tindallsb2b.co.uk/storefront/evolution_ProductResults.html?strSearch=" + searchlink;
            webBrowser.Url = new Uri(link);

        }

        private void urlcheckertextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            urlcheckertextbox.Text = webBrowser.Url.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

When button is clicked, it navigates the domain to a "unknown location" page on the website (The website is not owned by me).

The idea is to click the cell in the DataGridView which is a product code, then click the button which adds the product code to the set url and loads the url+string in the webBrowser.

Comment: you have a string searchlink = ""; but you never attain any value to that variable.

Comment: I'm unsure what wouls be going into this.

Comment: from where you are supposed to get the postfix of your URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vairable `searchlink` isn't visible to your `orderbutton_Click()`. A solution would be to declare the varible `searchlink` outside of the methods in your class. In fact you are using  completely different variables (both named `searchlink`) inside your methods.
So for example:

```
class testclass
{
     string teststring1 = ""; //visible in both methods

     private void testmethod1()
     {
         string teststring2 = ""; //only visible in this method
         teststring1 = "it works!";
     }

     private void testmethod2()
     {
         teststring2 = "this won't compile"; //teststring2 is not visible here
         teststring1 = "it works, too";

         //but what you are doing is:
         string teststring2 = ""; //new variable (not related to teststring2 from above)
     }
}
```

And as [bkribbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4450618/bkribbs) told me this is called a variable scope. Thanks!

For solving your specific problem here is the new code:

```
string searchlink = "";

private void inkGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (inkGridView.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
        {
            int selectedrowindex = inkGridView.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

            DataGridViewRow selectedRow = inkGridView.Rows[selectedrowindex];

            searchlink = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["tonerInkDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
        }
    }

    private void orderbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string link;

        link = "http://store.tindallsb2b.co.uk/storefront/evolution_ProductResults.html?strSearch=" + searchlink;
        webBrowser.Url = new Uri(link);

    }
```

I hope I got your problem right :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75969/discussion-on-answer-by-jibbow-button-click-url-string).